# The existence of local maximum and minimum of a real-valued function

Tags: real-analysis

I think it's very clever to show that if $f$ has a local maximum (or minimum) at a point $x\in(a,b)$ and $f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(x)=0$, for $$a<x-\epsilon <x<x+\epsilon <b,$$ and so the quotient $\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\geq0 $, if $x-\epsilon <t<x$

and $\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\leq0 $, if $x <t<x+\epsilon$, hence $\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=0$.

But what can be said about the existence of local maxima or minima?

If $f$ is a real-valued function defined on $[a,b]$, would the (generalised) mean value theorem be enough to imply that there exists a point $x \in [a,b]$ that is either a local maximum or local minimum, *given that $f$ is not constant?*

Thanks.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: yes, $f$ is continuous

Comment: What @Hagen is getting at is that there's a theorem that says continuous functions on closed and finite intervals always achieve their absolute extrema.

Comment: Also, why do you emphasize that $f$ shoul dnot be constant? Do you want *strict* local extrema?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I see, for $f$ that is continuous on a closed interval, the Extreme Value theorem states that global max/min exist, hence local max/ min also exist on this interval. @ Hagen yes, I was thinking about a specific case. Are all points of a constant function simultaneously global maxima and minima? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, wait. You're talking about local extrema. $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ is a counter-example. End-points cannot be local extrema, because local extrema must have a symmetric neighborhood on both sides where the value is the extreme value. Absolute extrema are not necessarily local, and local are not necessarily absolute.

Comment: @AdrianKeister If one defines that $f\colon X\to\BbbR$ has a local minimum at $x\in X$ if there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $X$ such that $f(y)\ge f(x)$ for all $y\in U$, then there is no such thing as two-sided. In fact, in $[a,b]$, $[a,a+\epsilon)$ is a neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: @Hagen: I think many authors require a neighborhood of a point $c$ to be an open set containing $c$, in which case it will have to be two-sided.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - they require it to be open *with respect to the function's domain*. If $X = [a,b]$, then $[a, a+ \epsilon)$ and $(b - \epsilon, b]$ are open with respect to $X$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: No doubt you are right that some authors define a neighborhood that way. It is a fact that some don't. Stewart's Calculus, for example, has this: A function $f$ has a *local maximum* (or *relative maximum*) at $c$ if $f(c)\ge f(x)$ when $x$ is near $c$. [This means that $f(c)\ge f(x)$ for all $x$ in some open interval containing $c$.] An open interval he defines in an appendix as the usual $(a,b)=\{x\,|\,a<x<b\}$. This definition rules out local extrema being at endpoints.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - there is a bigger world out there that apparently you are not aware of yet. I can assure you that if Stewart actually did rule out local extrema at the boundaries (your snippets fall well short of demonstrating this), he did so unintentionally. You should interpret "$x$ near $c$" to mean "$x$ in the domain of $f$ near $c$". I think it likely that if you examine the book carefully, that restriction to the domain of $f$ is at least implicit, and may actually be stated explicitly, but you've overlooked it.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I agree with Paul. More on the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763340/are-global-extrema-local-extrema).

Comment: @PaulSinclair See above. :)

Comment: Re: Paul and Mark: I am actually quite aware of these alternative definitions, and I have a hard time believing that the calculus book authors are not aware of them. There's nothing lost by defining relative extrema in such a way that endpoints can't be local extrema. All calculus books I've seen tell students explicitly to check endpoints to see if they are absolute extrema. From the very thread Mark linked to, it is evident from some of the other answers that other folks agree with me. This is not a very significant issue, except that authors should be clear which definition they're using.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - the problem is, your concept of "local extrema" is not determined only by the various properties of a function $f$ (domain (a topological space), codomain (an ordered space), and relation). You have it depending on a choice of space you consider the domain of $f$ to be a part of. This is foreign to the function itself, and makes the concept of local extremum relative. For example, the domain of any real function sits in $\Bbb C$, and as viewed as such, $f$ cannot have any local extrema, as every point now has neighbors outside the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to write an answer to close this question.

From the fairly long discussion in the comment section, for a function $f$ that is continuous on a closed interval, the Extreme Value Theorem states that global maxima and minima exist in this interval, hence local maxima and minima also exist in the interval.

From this other question [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763340/are-global-extrema-local-extrema), I will refer to the fact that

- If global extrema is not in boundary, i.e. point $x \in (a,b)$, then it is also local extrema in that (open) interval.

And since the proof that, 'if $f$ has local extrema and $f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(x)=0$' is concerning a point $x$ in the *open* interval $(a,b)$, we don't necessarily have to settle the debate on what happens if global extrema exists on the boundary of the interval.